# C++ SFINAE with interface

Tags: c++, class, interface, shared-ptr, sfinae

I can't understand how i can create expr object from double in expr.cpp file.

**expr_base:**

The base class of all expressions. Note that all expression classes
(including this base) are private to the implementation and should not
be exposed to other code. The rest of the program should use
expressions *only* via `expr`.

This subclasses `std::enable_shared_from_this` to enable getting
shared_ptr to this from a method.

**expr:**

Wrapper around dynamically allocated instances of expr_base. This type
has value semantics and since all subclasses of expr_base are
immutable, shallow copies are made.

This type has overloaded functions and operators, so that expression
construction is easy and readable.

**error:**

```
     error: no viable conversion from returned value of type 'typename enable_if<!is_array<number>::value,
      shared_ptr<number> >::type' (aka 'std::__1::shared_ptr<exprs::number>') to function return type 'expr'
    return std::make_shared<exprs::number>(n);
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     /..../expr.hpp(...): note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'typename enable_if<!is_array<number>::value, shared_ptr<number> >::type' (aka 'std::__1::shared_ptr<exprs::number>') to 'const expr &' for 1st argument
class expr final {
      ^
     /.../expr.hpp:(...): note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'typename enable_if<!is_array<number>::value, shared_ptr<number> >::type' (aka 'std::__1::shared_ptr<exprs::number>') to 'expr &&' for 1st argument
    
     /.../expr.hpp:(...): note: candidate template ignored: requirement 'std::is_convertible<exprs::number *, const expr_base*>::value' was not satisfied [with T = exprs::number]
    expr(std::shared_ptr<T> e): ptr(std::static_pointer_cast<const expr_base>(std::move(e))) {}
```

**expr.hpp**

```
...
class expr;

class expr_base: public std::enable_shared_from_this<expr_base>
{
    friend class expr;
    protected:
        expr_base() = default;
    public:
        using variable_map_t = std::map<std::string, double>;
        virtual ~expr_base() = default;
};


class expr final {
    private:
        using const_pointer = std::shared_ptr<const expr_base>;
    public:
        using variable_map_t = expr_base::variable_map_t;

        template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<T*, const expr_base*>::value>>
        expr(std::shared_ptr<T> e): ptr(std::static_pointer_cast<const expr_base>(std::move(e))) {}

        expr() = default;

        static expr number(double n);

        operator const_pointer const &() const {return ptr;}
        const expr_base* operator->() const {assert(ptr.get() != nullptr); return ptr.get();}
    private:
        const_pointer ptr;
};
```

**expr.cpp**

```
...
#include "expr.hpp"
#include "expr_impl.hpp"
    
expr expr::number(double n) {
    return std::make_shared<exprs::number>(n); // It doesn't work 
}
```

**expr_impl.hpp**

```
...
#include "expr.hpp"

namespace exprs {
    class number:expr_base {
    private:
        double num_;

    public:
        number(double num): num_(num) {};
    };
}
```

Comment: `class number:expr_base` needs to be `class number: public expr_base`